# Storing/retrieving huge numbers from relational DB with Go

Tags: postgresql, go

What is a proper way to represent huge numbers from database in GO?

I have a Postgres table with column of `numeric` type. Postgres internally represents it as `varchar`, allowing it to have virtually unlimited size. My values won't exceed `10 ^ 28` tough. Additionally, this column is `nullable`.

I know that go has `big.Int` for representing such numbers, but there is no nullable equivalent in `sql` package, `sql.NullInt64` being the biggest out there.

So what is a proper way of representing such column in go?

Comment: Does a pointer to `big.Int` work for you? `*big.Int` may be `nil` which would be SQL `null`.

Comment: In case you don't want to use pointers, implementing a custom `NullBigInt` should be very simple, you can look at the [implementations](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/sql.go#L175-L209) in the standard library for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Had to convert `*big.Int` to `string` before insertion, and store value in `string` temporarily on reading, but it works